# Django: Reference to an outer query may only be used in a subquery

Tags: django

I use the following queries:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(topic_id=OuterRef('pk'))
    unread_posts = posts.exclude(read_by=self.request.user)
    return Topic.objects.all().annotate(is_unread=Exists(unread_posts),
                                        number_of_replies=Subquery(posts.count())).order_by('-latest_post')
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

```
This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.
```

I'm confused because I explicitly set `Subquery(posts.count())`.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: The problem is that `.count()` will eagerly execute the query, it will try to return an `int`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that `.count()` is something that evaluates the query eagerly, and thus `Subquery(..)` is never used. But even if that would work, it is not a good idea to do so anyway.

You can just count with a JOIN, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Exists, OuterRef

def get_queryset(self):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(topic_id=OuterRef('pk'))
    unread_posts = posts.exclude(read_by=self.request.user)
    return Topic.objects.annotate(
        is_unread=Exists(unread_posts),
        number_of_replies=Count('post')
    ).order_by('-latest_post')
```